# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<String.Index>' with an argument list of type '(start: String.Index, end: String.Index)'

Tags: string, swift3

```
let greenHex = hex.substring(with: Range<String.Index>(start: hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 2), end: hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)))
```

This is Swift3.0, hex is a string, but this code throws an error saying that:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range' with an
>   argument list of  type '(start: String.Index, end: String.Index)'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Range.init(start:end:)` constructor was removed in Swift 3.0 so you initialize a range like follows:

```
let range = hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)..<hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
```

which returns a *half-open* range of type `<String.Index>`. Then, you can do the following with that:

```
hex.substring(with: range)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I got the answer. I write the code just like you say, it works.